# Can't save data to core data on main thread or private thread

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Yesterday I was able to save records to core data but then I did a little bit of refactoring in my project to make my code cleaner(mostly code from my DTO where I encode / decode data with NSCoder and created separate files for my custom value transformers)

After that I noticed saving data stopped working, this is my code for adding:

```
 let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    func add(pet: PetDTO) {
        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.perform {
            let newPet = PetEntity(context: managedObjectContext)
            
            newPet.id = Int64(pet.id)
            newPet.name = pet.name
            newPet.category = pet.category
            newPet.photoUrls = pet.photoUrls
            newPet.tags = pet.tags
            newPet.status = pet.status.rawValue
            do {
                try self.context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

I It seems that I am missing something related to contexts. I created this `managedObjectContext`  and from what I understand, I had to save data on this context, but nothing happens. I tried removing `let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)` and saving on main context but I had this error:

```
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x600000156640> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred."
```

I managed to solve it only by adding another context and passing it to PetEntity.

So the question is: **what am I doing wrong? Can I somehow merge contexts? I've seen a method for that but not sure if I need it.**

Thanks

**Update:**
Changed my code to this:

```
 do {
       try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
        print(error)
     }
```

Just realized wasn't saving it on the right context. Now I have `nilError` and it still didn't save into the database. I think it happens because I get bad data from Json, my category field is sometimes nil and that's why it shows that error, am I right?

And about getting data from Core data, now I fetch it from main context, but the data is being saved on another context, what can I do here to fix this?

Comment: The NSManagedObjectContext you have created isn't connected to a persistent store (container) so it doesn't know anything about your core data model and entities

Comment: My advice if you are not experienced with Core Data is to skip any solution using multiple context and only use your main one that you access via the app delegate. Then later on if you have a specific use case then research and implement a solution with multiple instances of  NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thanks, will try your first solution